# Get the value from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have some code I need help with:

```
var bob = [10,30,50,20,8];

// Call the function

foo(bob);

var foo = function(bob){

 var max = 0,
 min = 0,
 average = 0,
 sum = 0;

 max = Math.max.apply( null, bob); // Get the max value.
 min = Math.min.apply( null, bob); // Get the min value.


 for( var i = 0; i < bob.length; i++ ){
  sum += bob[ i ];
 }

 average = sum / l;

 var resultArr = [];

 resultArr[0] = average;
 resultArr[1] = min;
 resultArr[2] = max;

 return resultArr;
}


document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = "Max value: "; // i want to print the max value here.
```

This function returns an array with max, min and average values. How can I choose which value to print in different divs?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer:

```
var resultArr = foo(bob);
document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = resultArr[2];
document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = resultArr[1];
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = resultArr[2];
```

Or

```
<div id="max">
    <script>document.write(resultArr[2]);</script>
</div>
```

Or (JQuery)

```
$('#max').val(resultArr[2]);
```

Comment: I tried this. but Firebug gives me this error: resultArr is not defined
document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = "Max value: " + resultArr[2];

Comment: @Ferrari, you must do `resultArr = foo(bob);` first

Comment: @Ferrari resultArr is a variable holding the result of the function foo.You would first have to initialize that variable : var resultArr = foo([10,30,50,20,8]);  or whatever array do you need to process

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of things confused here. You have a global variable `bob` and you also have `bob` as a function argument. Also, you have an array of results, which *local to the `foo` function* is called `resultArr`, but *you do not assign it anywhere* when you call the `foo` function.

Try the following code instead:

```
var bob = [10,30,50,20,8];

var foo = function(arrayOfNumbers){
  var resultObj = {
    max: 0,
    min: 0,
    average: 0,
    sum: 0
  };

  resultObj.max = Math.max.apply( null, arrayOfNumbers); // Get the max value.
  resultObj.min = Math.min.apply( null, arrayOfNumbers); // Get the min value.

  for( var i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++ ){
    resultObj.sum += arrayOfNumbers[ i ];
  }

  resultObj.average = sum / l;

  return resultObj;
}

// Call the function

var theResult = foo(bob);

document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = "Max value: "+theResult.max;
```

Here's a description of the changes I made to your code, and why:

1. I made sure that the names of your variables don't conflict. This should help you see where each variable is used and how they relate to each other. `bob` contains your numbers. You pass `bob` to the `foo()` function. Inside `foo`, the numbers are now referred to as `v`. This means you could also have `frank`, `joe`, and `tom`, and you could call `foo` on all of them. `arrayOfNumbers` is a local variable to `foo`.
2. I changed `resultArr` from an array to an object. An object makes more sense because you can assign labels to the values. So now the max value is can be accessed at `.max` instead of `[0]`. I also showed how the result object is called `resultObj` *inside* `foo` but gets assigned to `theResult` *outside* foo. You can then refer to `theResult.min`, `theResult.max`, and `theResult.average`.
3. I cleaned up a little bit, fixing indentation and moving the function to the top, to increase readability.

I hope this helps you see what's going on here!